# Add buttons to the menu of a Chrome Extension sidePanel?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When using the sidePanel of a Chrome Extension is there any way to add items to the menu?
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/

This image shows the selected extension and an "x" button to close it. Is there a way to add other buttons and have the extension respond to them when clicked?

[image]

Comment: No, these are built-in UI elements. Chrome doesn't allow extensions to customize its UI.